# Why am I Getting This GeoCode Error

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is what I'm getting when I try to make a post on my site. What do I need to do to fix?

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /home/dfwwrightimc/public_html/wp-content/themes/visitdfw/functions.php on line 351

```
function geo_lat_long($address) {
    $address1 = str_replace(" ","+",$address);
    $address1 = str_replace("&","%26",$address1);
    $json = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address1");
    $json = json_decode($json);
    $lat = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
    $long = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};
    return array('lat' => $lat, 'long' => $long);
}
```

Comment: Just so you know you don't have to use `{'results'}` with std objects unless they have unsupported symbols in them (so like dashes`-`). You could just go `$json->results[0]->geometry->location->lat`

Comment: Maybe you should use `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/` as specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingRequests)

Answer (score 0):

Change the following lines:

```
$address1 = str_replace(" ","+",$address);
$address1 = str_replace("&","%26",$address1);
$json = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address1");
```

to

```
$address1 = urlencode ( $address );
$json = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address1");
```

and try again.

**Explanation:** The error `Bad Request` is related to the incorrect URL.

```
urlencode — URL-encodes string

string urlencode ( string $str )
```

This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page.

Comment: Now, I'm getting this when I make that edit:
Warning: file_get_contents(http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /home/dfwwrightimc/public_html/wp-content/themes/visitdfw/functions.php on line 350

Comment: @johnc is there an address being passed? can you check? store the URL in a string and echo beforehand - looking at this there is no address being passed?

Answer (score 0):

Check how you are calling the `geo_lat_long()` function. Is the address passed in correctly? Since the URL in the error message ends in `?address=` with no value, it looks like `$address1` is empty.

Comment: I"m new to this, so what would the value be?